# How do you find variance?

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and finite variance.

$$T_n= \binom{n}{2}^{-1} \sum_{1\leq i< j\leq n} {X_{i}X_{j}} $$

> I have to calculate $Var(T_{n})$.

Comment: What you have done?

Answer (score -1):

$$Var(X_1 X_2)=E(X_1^2 X_2^2)-E(X_1X_2)^2=(\sigma^2+\mu^2)^2-\mu^4=\sigma^4+2\sigma^2\mu^2$$

$$Var(T_n)=\binom{n}{2}^{-1} Var(X_1 X_2)=\frac{\sigma^4+2\sigma^2\mu^2}{n (n-1)/2}$$

Comment: $$Var(\binom{n}{2}^{-1} \sum_{1\leq i< j\leq n} {X_{i}X_{j}}) = (\binom{n}{2}^{-1})^2 Var(\sum_{1\leq i< j\leq n} {X_{i}X_{j}}) = (\binom{n}{2}^{-1})^2 \binom{n}{2} Var(X_{1}X_{2})$$
But how do you know that  $$Var (\sum_{1\leq i< j\leq n} {X_{i}X_{j}})=\binom{n}{2} Var(X_{1}X_{2})$$

Comment: You missed the -1 above the binom

Comment: $Var(T_n)=\binom{n}{2}^{\color{red}{-1}}...$

Comment: Okey, but why you don't consider $Cov(X_{i}X_{j},X_{i}X_{j+1})$? Is it zero?